# increasing performance of a query with a generated list, a list and a lateral cross join

Tags: postgresql

I got 2 relevant tables: people and shifts.
My goal is to retrieve a shift for each day in the timeframe for a list of people.
That means even in case there is no shift I want to get a result with the date, the person_id and the rest can be null.

```
people table:
id | name | deptartment_id
---|------|-------------
1  | max  | 1
2  | tim  | 1

shifts table:
id | date_of_shift | person_id
---|---------------|----------
1  | 2016-03-22    | 1
2  | 2016-03-23    | 1
3  | 2016-03-24    | 1
4  | 2016-03-21    | 2
5  | 2016-03-23    | 2
6  | 2016-03-25    | 2
```

this is the query I managed to create:

```
SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          json_agg(DISTINCT(shi)) as shifts

     FROM people as p
     JOIN LATERAL
            (SELECT d.date_of_shift,
                    pe.id as person_id,
                    sh.shift_id
               FROM generate_series('2016-03-21'::date, '2016-03-25', interval '1 day') AS d(date_of_shift)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
                    SELECT people.id
                      FROM people
                    ) AS pe
         LEFT JOIN( SELECT shifts.id as shift_id,
                           shifts.person_id,
                           shifts.date_of_shift
                     FROM shifts
                     ) as sh
                 ON d.date_of_shift = sh.date_of_shift AND sh.person_id = pe.id
           ) AS shi
       ON p.id = shi.person_id

    WHERE p.id IN (SELECT people.id
                        FROM people
                       WHERE people.department_id = 1
                    ORDER BY people.id ASC)
 GROUP BY p.id, p.name;
```

The result I hope to get would look like this:

```
 id |   name   |                                      shifts                                      
----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | person0  | [{"date_of_shift":"2016-03-21T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":2,"shift_id":null},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-22T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":2,"shift_id":1027},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-23T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":2,"shift_id":1028},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-24T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":2,"shift_id":1029},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-25T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":2,"shift_id":1030}]
  3 | person1  | [{"date_of_shift":"2016-03-21T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":3,"shift_id":1781},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-22T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":3,"shift_id":1782},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-23T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":3,"shift_id":1783},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-24T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":3,"shift_id":1784},   +
    |          |  {"date_of_shift":"2016-03-25T00:00:00+01:00","person_id":3,"shift_id":1785}]
```

I faced multiple problem which led to this very slow query

1. I want a shift for each day, even if there is no shift in the db
2. I have a list of people (all people in a certain department)

I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0111d4/1) to show the problem.
With the amount of data I have in my dev db it takes 1 sec the run the query.
And 1 sec for a query that will display all relevant data of the main page in my SPA is not really viable. It is more of a private project, but I'm really interested to see how the problem could be solved more efficiently.

[this](http://explain.depesz.com/s/TkkZ) would be the result of EXPLAIN ANAYLIZE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while still being in bed I had a breakthrough.

The 2nd join on the people table is completely unnecessary and I can LEFT JOIN shifts directly on the generated date series

```
            SELECT p.id,
                   p.name,
                   json_agg(s) as shifts
              FROM people as p
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT d.date_of_shift, sh.id as shift_id
                      FROM generate_series('2016-03-21'::date, '2016-03-25', interval '1 day') AS d(date_of_shift)
         LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT shifts.id, 
                                   shifts.person_id, 
                                   shifts.date_of_shift
                              FROM shifts
                           ) as sh
                        ON d.date_of_shift = sh.date_of_shift AND sh.person_id = p.id) as s
             WHERE p.id IN (SELECT people.id
                              FROM people
                             WHERE people.department_id = 1)
             GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

the query now takes 25ms instead of 980ms

Comment: The query above doesn't work:
`ERROR:  relation "shift_types" does not exist  LINE 13: JOIN shift_types`

Comment: yea I updated the query after I formated it to look nicer, but by the time I already added another join for a table that is not in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I would try to split the query with a Common Table Expression (WITH clause), as that really improves the legibility of the query. Can you see if this query runs faster?

```sql
WITH shifts_per_person AS (
  SELECT d.date_of_shift, p.id AS person_id, shifts.id AS shift_id
  FROM people AS p
  CROSS JOIN generate_series('2016-03-21'::date, '2016-03-25', interval '1 day') AS d(date_of_shift)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts ON shifts.person_id = p.id AND shifts.date_of_shift = d.date_of_shift
  ORDER BY p.id, d.date_of_shift)

SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       json_agg(row_to_json(s.*)) as shifts
FROM people AS p
JOIN shifts_per_person AS s ON p.id = s.person_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to take a look at my question. I already had an idea this morning and already answered my question. but I missed a small detail so I deleted the question until I could fix my mistake. My biggest mistake was to do a second join on the people table. My query now takes 20ms instead of 800 ;). thanks again for taking a look

Comment: @Elux91 perhaps you could approve my answer, as: 1. it actually works and 2. the code is much less convoluted than in the accepted answer